# Binding a decimal value with InvariantCulture

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, decimal, culture

I have a `TextBox` which is bound to a decimal property.

Our requirment is to have a `InvariantCulture` behaviour.

When a user types `6.30`, the value needs to be `6,30`

If a user types `6,30`, the value needs to be `6,30`

Currently the binding sets the value to `630` when a dot is used.

Is this possible?

Comment: I ran into so many problems with this stuff that i mostly just do all the checking myself, the easiest way of doing this is to subscribe a event for textchanged on the textbox and do this **textbox1.Text = textbox1.Text.Replace('.',',');** .

Comment: @Vajura - what if someone enters `123,456.78` or `123.456,78` respectively (both meaning `123456.78` in different cultures)?

Comment: @Vajura That is not possible for me, because I use WPF binding. It works totally different than the winforms way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirement is in fact not the behavior of `InvariantCulture`. You want to allow users to type in both forms of number with decimal point being either `.` or `,`. This kind of dynamic expression of course should need some custom converter. Try this custom converter:

```
public class MultiCultureNumberConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone() 
                 as System.Globalization.CultureInfo;
        ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
        return ((decimal)value).ToString(ci);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone() as 
                 System.Globalization.CultureInfo;
        var s = System.Convert.ToString(value);
        decimal d;
        if (decimal.TryParse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number 
                  ^ System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands, ci, out d))
        {
            return d;
        }
        else
        {
            ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
            if (decimal.TryParse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number 
                ^ System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands, ci, out d)) 
              return d;
        }
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Comment: With that ([NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.invariantinfo.aspx)) I'd expect it to work correctly (as in: like expected) for `6.30`, but wouldn't now `6,30` be turned into `630`? It looks like OP is looking for a way to have two different decimal separators, which is not easily doable as far as I know.

Comment: I get a `The name "CultureInfo" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=System.Globalization"` error

Comment: @Corak you're right, I was just too concentrated on his requirement of setting the culture to `InvariantCulture`, while it should always display `.` as `.` in such culture.

Comment: @DeMama not sure how there was such an error, I've tried the code on my side first. Anyway this does set the culture but it does not help with your requirement (always show `.` as `,`).

Comment: @KingKing Then i'll solve it some other way, nothing to do about it. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @DeMama you can try setting the `Language` property instead, choose some specific culture language which always uses `,` instead of `.`. For example: Language="vi-VN"

Comment: I don't think it's a problem of display, but a problem of converting string input into a decimal value. So if a user writes `"6.30"` into the textbox, it should result in the decimal value `6.30m`, and if a user writes `"6,30"` into the textbox, it should also result in the decimal value `6.30m`.

Comment: @Corak Correct. We have a touchscreen application which can recieve input from a keyboard or an on-screen keyboard. In our 'culture' we use comma as a decimal separator. But when typing a price using a keyboard it's much easier to use the `dot-del` button.

Comment: Very nice @KingKing ! Thanks